# A sweeper bot knows one of my ETH private key. What should I do?

Tags: myetherwallet

I had a private key which I accidentally pasted on a group instead of pasting it on my notes (*yeah it was dumb*). Fortunately, I expected someone managed to save it even though I deleted it in an instant so I never used it.

But I tried putting an amount 0.0001 ETH and it was automatically sent to a burn address as a fee.

Is there a way to cancel the sweeper bot? Or a way to encrypt an existing ETH Priv key, with a password like bip38 in bitcoin?

Answer (score 2):

No. Private key is the ultimate access mechanism to your account. It gives direct access to the account and it doesn't help anything anymore if you encrypt it with a password as someone already has it.

What you should do is simply start a new account with a new private key. It's super easy in whichever client you are using. Then just forget about the old account.

Comment: What if I make and use another sweeper bot? Will that void the first bot?

Comment: Nothing will void the fact that someone has your private key.